Why the input eventlistener with change is not getting the value
I have these three inputs of type number where you can only add one number and you can replace it by pressing any other number between 0 and 9. I have 2 eventlisteners on these inputs the first is to be able to change the value of the inputs by pressing a number between 0 and 9 (by using 'keyup').
The second eventlistener is there for detecting input and then calculating the total of the three input, when the correct total is calculated an alert is thrown. What I have noticed is if I want a total of 27 for example I need to add 9 + 9 + 9 in inputs.
However if I add 9 + 8 + 9 but then without deleting the 8 and just replacing it by pressing 9 I don't get the alert. To get the total the better seems to do it within the event listener with 'keyup'.
So why is that? When pressing the 9 button it is still an input event as well?


const element1 = document.querySelector('.element1')
let total = 0
let desiredTotal = 27

    let allInputs = Array.from(element1.getElementsByTagName('input'))
    allInputs.forEach((input)=>{
        input.style.border = '2px solid blue'
        input.addEventListener('keyup', (e)=>{
            if(e.target.value.length === 1 && parseFloat(e.key) >= 0 && parseFloat(e.key) <=9){
                    e.target.value = e.key
            }
        })
    })


    allInputs.forEach((input)=>{
        let value
        input.addEventListener('input', (e)=>{
            let value = parseFloat(input.value)
            total += value
            console.log(total)
            if(total === 27) alert('you won!')
        })

    })
input{
    width: 2ch;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  appearance: textfield;
}
<body>
    <div class="element1">
        <input type="number" name="" id="input1" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length===1 || event.key == 'e') {return false}">
        <input type="number" name="" id="input2" onKeyPress="if(this.value.length===1 || event.key == 'e') {return false}">
        <input type="number" name="" id="input3"onKeyPress="if(this.value.length===1 || event.key == 'e') {return false}">
    </div>
    <p>Try to obtain a total of 27</p>
    <p>Try to place 9 9 and then 9 you get the alert</p>
    <p>Try to place 9 6 and then 9 but then change(without deleting) but pressing on the 6 containing input the number 9 you won't get the alert</p>
</body>




It's the onKeyPress event that stops input event from triggering after the first time because you used return false. Deleting the number will make it pass the onKeyPress and trigger input again. Order: keydown => keypress => input => keyup

thanks a lot @LãNgọcHải for a precise explanation of évents sequence took me some times to set it clear in my mind, but now I perfectly understand

Don't mix HTML input onKeyPress and JS EventListener.
Do everything in JS


document.querySelectorAll('.element1 input').forEach( (inElm,_,All) =>
  {
  inElm.addEventListener('keydown', e =>
    {
    if (/\d/.test(e.key)) e.target.value = e.key; // accept only digitals 
 
    if (e.key !== 'Tab')  e.preventDefault();    // do ignore input event

    let Total = 0;
    All.forEach( inN => Total += inN.valueAsNumber );

    console.clear();
    console.log( 'Total', Total );
    });
  });
input[type="number"] {
  width      : 2ch;
  border     : 2px solid blue;
  text-align : center;
  margin     : .5em;
  appearance : textfield;
  }
<div class="element1">
  <input type="number" value="0" >
  <input type="number" value="0" >
  <input type="number" value="0" >
</div>
<p>Try to obtain a total of 27</p>




Thank you so much @Mister Jojo you are right should be using only one évent listener wiIth just JS no need for onkeypressed. I also liké the RegExp part
